# Setting a callback function in mutationobserver not working for puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

If I use page.exposeFunction inside ObserveElement.js file it detects mutation but when I set a callback then call it in other file it doesn't work. Did I miss something in my code?

```
//ObserveElement.js

async function ObserveElement(page, callback, parentElement) {
  const targetDiv = await parentElement.$('.title-info');

  const disconnect = await page.evaluate((targetDiv) => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        const scoresInfo = mutation.target.innerText;
        callback(scoresInfo); 
      });
    });

    observer.observe(targetDiv, { attributes: true });

    // Return the disconnect function
    return () => observer.disconnect();
  }, targetDiv);

  return disconnect;
}

module.exports = ObserveElement;
```

Main file

```
//Main.js

const main = async () => {
  //page url code hidden

  const parentElement = await page.$$('parent-class'); 

  const myCallback = (info) => {
    console.log("myCallback");
    console.log(info);
  };

  await ObserveDotaTeam(page, myCallback, parentElement );

}
```